# Emacs stop working in Mac OSX Catalina. How to fix?

Tags: macos, emacs

I keep getting this error:

> emacs dyld: Library not loaded:
> /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.6.dylib   Referenced from:
> /usr/local/opt/p11-kit/lib/libp11-kit.0.dylib   Reason: image not
> found Abort trap: 6

I tried to reinstall with `brew reinstall emacs`, `brew install libffi`, `brew link libffi`. Nothing helps.

Comment: These days I'm using railiwaycat's brew for the emacs mac port, which is working fine under Catalina. Have you tried removing emacs and instlaling using the binary cask (as suggested in the emacs source recipe info?)

Comment: I had the same issue, and `brew upgrade emacs` resolved it.

Comment: How did you solved it?

Emacs was working just fine, but it crashed. Now I get that error.

Comment: A `brew reinstall emacs-mac` fixed it.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to macOS Catalina `10.15.4`. I got this error:

```
$ emacs file.txt
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/p11-kit/lib/libp11-kit.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Reinstalling `emacs` with brew solved the problem.

```
brew reinstall emacs
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem installing from source,

```
brew reinstall p11-kit
```

was the fix for me

Comment: This worked for me too. Although i did `brew upgrade p11-kit` When upgrading p11-kit it automatically upgraded emacs as it was a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but different issues:

```
dyld[5893]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.23/bin/php
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file)
```

It works for me:

```
brew reinstall libffi
```

Comment: I was having this issue with `scrcpy`, reinstalling libffi fixed it!

$ scrcpy
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/p11-kit/lib/libp11-kit.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Reinstalling "libffi" eats my internet bandwidth :(

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue while using `scrapy shell` command

Solved this using

`pip3 install --force-reinstall cryptography` on Mac OS